# Get output of multiple Counts in one query

Tags: sql-server

Could you help me how to write a query for the following issue:
There are two tables:
Table persons:

```
P_id     Name     BirthDate
1            N1       2016-08-02
2            N2       2015-05-02
3            N3       2013-06-01
4            N4       2014-01-09
```

Table visited:(p_id is foreign key to table persons)

```
Id.     Visitor_id.     P_id.     Visit_date
1          10              1         2017-03-05
2          11              2         2017-01-01
3          10              2         2017-02-03
4          12              3         2016-05-07
5          11              4         2016-04-09
6          10              1         2017-04-09
```

We are going to get the count of visited by each Visitor and also count of visited distinct person on filter on for those person who their age are under 1, between 1 and 2, between 2 and 3 at date of visit_date by each visitor_id.
The results should be like :

```
                    Under_one                       Bet_one_two                        Bet_two_three 
Visitor_id      VisitedCount/PersonCount        VisitedCount/PersonCount        VisitedCount/PersonCount
10                  2             1             1             1                    0           0
11                  0             0             1             1                    1           1
12                  0             0             0             0                    1           1
```

Between 1 and 2 means the result of subtracting visited_date and birthdate (for example : the result of 2013/03/05 - 2011/06/07) is between 1 and 2 years.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I can give you the output laid out exactly as you have specified, but this

```
SELECT
 visited.Visitor_id,
 visited.P_id,
 Int(([Visit_date]-[BirthDate])/365) AS Age,
 Count(persons.P_id) AS NumVisits
FROM persons INNER JOIN visited ON persons.P_id = visited.P_id
GROUP BY
 visited.Visitor_id,
 visited.P_id,
 Int((-[BirthDate]+[Visit_date])/365);
```

returns

```
Visitor_id  P_id    Age NumVisits
   10        1       0     2
   10        2       1     1
   11        2       1     1
   11        4       2     1
   12        3       2     1
```